# Menu dropdown com duas colunas?

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

Fala galera. to quebrando a cabeça aqui pois quero deixar o menu dropdown com duas colunas e ta bugando.

[image: a coluna do lado fica como se tivesse uma margin-top]

**CSS**

```
  /* Navigation */
```

.menuheadx{position:fixed;width:100%;margin:auto;top:0;right:0;left:0;opacity:1;z-index:999;-webkit-transform:translateZ(0);transform:translateZ(0);background:linear-gradient(180deg,#0b0d11 0,rgba(0,0,0,.9));color:#fff;transition:transform .3s;box-shadow:0 2px 6px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);transition:background-color .25s linear}
.logo{position:relative;padding:7px 0;color:#fff;float:left;z-index:123}.logo a{color:#fff}#menuhead nav{position:relative;width:100%;max-width:990px;margin:0 auto}
#csxmenus,#csxmenus ul,#csxmenus ul li,#csxmenus ul li a,#csxmenus #head-mobile{border:0;list-style:none;line-height:1;margin:0 auto;display:block;position:relative}#csxmenus{width:100%;max-width:990px}#csxmenus:after,#csxmenus > ul:after{content:".";display:block;clear:both;visibility:hidden;line-height:0;height:0}#csxmenus #head-mobile{display:none}#csxmenus > ul > li{float:left}#csxmenus > ul > li > a{padding:20px 10px;font-size:14px;font-weight:500;letter-spacing:1px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff}#csxmenus > ul > li > a:before{background:#1277cb;content:'';display:block;position:absolute;left:100%;right:100%;bottom:0;height:1px;transition:all .3s ease-in-out}#csxmenus > ul > li > a:hover:before,#csxmenus > ul > li:hover > a:before{left:10px;right:10px}#csxmenus > ul > li:hover > a,#csxmenus ul li.active a{color:#fff}#csxmenus > ul > li:hover,#csxmenus ul li.active:hover,#csxmenus ul li.active,#csxmenus ul li.has-sub.active:hover{transition:background .3s ease}#csxmenus ul ul{background:linear-gradient(180deg,#0b0d11 0,rgba(0,0,0,.9));position:absolute;opacity:0;visibility:hidden;z-index:99;box-shadow:0 2px 2.2rem -1rem rgba(0,0,0,0.1);transition:all .4s cubic-bezier(.47,1.64,.41,.8);border-radius:8px;top:100%;transform:scale(0.9);transform-style:preserve-3d;backface-visibility:hidden}#csxmenus ul ul li{transition:all .25s ease}#csxmenus ul ul li:hover{}#csxmenus li:hover > ul{opacity:1;visibility:visible;transform:scale(1.0)}#csxmenus li:hover > ul >li{}#csxmenus ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0}#csxmenus ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.03);padding:8px 15px;width:170px;font-size:13px;text-decoration:none;color:#fff;font-weight:400}#csxmenus ul ul li:last-child >a,#csxmenus ul ul li.last-item >a{border-bottom:0}#csxmenus ul ul li:hover >a,#csxmenus ul ul li a:hover{left:3px;}#csxmenus ul ul li.has-sub:hover,#csxmenus ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{}#csxmenus ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}#csxmenus >ul >li.has-sub >ul >li.active >a,#csxmenus > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.03)}#csxmenus > ul > li.has-sub >a i {margin:0 0 0 5px}#csxmenus > ul ul> li.has-sub >a i{margin:0 0 0 5px;float:right;transform:rotate(-90deg)}#csxmenus .notif-code{display:inline-block;font-size:18px;float:right;position:absolute;right:50px;top:19px;z-index:99}#csxmenus .notif-code a{position:relative;color:#fff}#csxmenus .notif-show .sindicat{display:block;font-size:16px;background:#1277cb;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:10px;height:10px;border-radius:8px}.sindicat{animation:sindicat 1s ease infinite}#csxmenus > ul > li > a.thisar{position:relative}#csxmenus > ul > li > a.thisar:after{content:'Ad';position:absolute;right:-3px;top:4px;background:#568af5;color:#fff;font-size:10px;padding:2px 5px;border-radius:3px}#csxmenus > ul > li:hover > a.thisar:after{animation:rubberBand 1.2s ease}.Night #csxmenus > ul > li > a.thisar:after{background:#ff9f43;color:#fff}#csxmenus ul ul li a:before{content:'\f114';font-family:fontawesome;margin:0 8px 0 0}#csxmenus ul ul li:hover a:before{content:'\f115';margin:0 6px 0 0}

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>LANÇAMENTOS</span></a></li>
  <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>SÉRIES</span></a></li>
 
  <li>
     <a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>GÊNEROS <i aria-hidden='true' class='fa fa-angle-down'/></span></a>
     <ul>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Ação</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Animação</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Aventura</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Comédia</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Crime</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Documentário</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Drama</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Fantasia</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Faroeste</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Ficção-Científica</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Guerra</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Musical</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Policial</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Romance</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Suspense</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Terror</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>Thriller</span></a></li>
       
     </ul>
  </li>
       <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>TOP IMDB</span></a></li>
       <li><a href='#' itemprop='url'><span itemprop='name'>AJUDA</span></a></li>
```

Comment: Cade o elemento com o ID `csxmenus`? Só esse CSS não me parece o CSS do menu inteiro, assim não da para simular o seu problema...

Comment: pronto ja adicionei

Answer (score -1):

Não tem como ver o problema ai, mas uma solução viável talvez seria você deixar esse menu do `:hover` com uma largura martelada, exemplo `300px` e também `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` e botar cada item do menu com `width: 150px`, assim ele ia ter duas linhas e quebrar automaticamente.

```css
#menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 320px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    #menu .item {
        width: 150px;
        background-color: #777;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<li>
        <a id="btn">
            Seu item
            <div id="menu">
                <a href="" class="item">item 1</a>
                <a href="" class="item">item 2</a>
                <a href="" class="item">item 3</a>
                <a href="" class="item">item 4</a>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: veja se consegue achar o problema agora